# JavaScript nested for loop resulting in displaying only last iterating object value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json array object which is getting constructed using two different array objects.
But after looping I'm getting the value of the last looped value for every array.

But for the serial number element I'm getting the value of the last iterated value. Am I missing something?

```js
for (z = 0; z < postAdvancedAddressCheckRequest.addressCheck.energyQuoteAddress.electricityMeter.length; z++) {
  for (i = 0; i < ecoesGetTechnicalDetailsByMpanResponse.Results[0].UtilityMatches.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ecoesGetTechnicalDetailsByMpanResponse.Results[0].UtilityMatches[i].Meters.length; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k < ecoesGetTechnicalDetailsByMpanResponse.Results[0].UtilityMatches[i].Meters[j].MeterDetails.length; k++) {
        if (ecoesGetTechnicalDetailsByMpanResponse.Results[0].UtilityMatches[i].Meters[j].MeterDetails[k].Key === "meter_serial_number") {
          var serialNumber1 = ecoesGetTechnicalDetailsByMpanResponse.Results[0].UtilityMatches[i].Meters[j].MeterDetails[k].Value;
        }
      }
      electricityMeterObject = {
        "Check": true,
        "serialNumber": serialNumber1
      }
      electricityArray.push(electricityMeterObject);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You create serialNumber1 inside "k" loop, but assign it inside "j" loop, ofc It'll be last of what it was in "k" loop.

Comment: you need to put within if condition to get every matching value

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add an example object and expected output

Comment: Also perhaps post the original arrays - perhaps we can help simplify this very ugly nested loop

Comment: NB: you should define your variables with `var` or `let` or `const`. Without that you implicitly define them as global variables, which is not best practice and may even lead to undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to debug

```js
const meter = postAdvancedAddressCheckRequest.addressCheck.energyQuoteAddress.electricityMeter,
  matches = ecoesGetTechnicalDetailsByMpanResponse.Results[0].UtilityMatches;
for (let z = 0; z < meter.length; z++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matches.Meters.length; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < matches[i].Meters[j].MeterDetails.length; k++) {
        if (matches[i].Meters[j].MeterDetails[k].Key === "meter_serial_number") {
          electricityArray.push({
            "Check": true,
            "serialNumber": matches[i].Meters[j].MeterDetails[k].Value
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```js
const meter = postAdvancedAddressCheckRequest.addressCheck.energyQuoteAddress.electricityMeter,
  matches = ecoesGetTechnicalDetailsByMpanResponse.Results[0].UtilityMatches;
meters.forEach(meter => {
  matches.forEach(match => {
    match.Meters.forEach(meter => {
      meter.MeterDetails.forEach(detail => {
        if(detail.Key === "meter_serial_number") {
          electricityArray.push({
            "Check": true,
            "serialNumber": matches[i].Meters[j].MeterDetails[k].Value
          });
        }
      })
    })
  })
})
```